# Form the taylor series for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{3^x}$ at the point $1$. For what numbers $x \in \Bbb R$ is the sum of the series $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Form the taylor series for the function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \frac{1}{3^x}$  at the point $1$. For what numbers $x \in \Bbb R$ is the sum of the series $f(x)$?

The taylor series is $$T_n(x,1)=f(1) + f'(1)(x-1) + \frac{f''(1)}{2!}(x-1)^2 + \dots$$

and $f'(x) = -\ln(3)\cdot3^{-x}, f''(x) = \ln(3)^2 \cdot 3^{-x}$ and in general $f^{(n)} = (-1)^n \ln(3)^n \cdot 3^{-x}$.

How can I figure out for what values of $x$ will the sum be equal to $\frac{1}{3^x}$?

I can get a nicer form for the series by $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\cdot \frac{\ln(3)^n}{3n!}(x-1)^n$$ but I still don't know what tools to use to find out the asked result?

Comment: Letting $x=1+h,$ your "nicer form" is that of the series $f(1+h)=\frac13e^{-h\ln3},$ and the exponential series is known to have an infinite [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) (by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)).

Comment: you are asked the radius of convergence of this power series, it is infinite by the ratio test, so the statement is true for all $x$.

Comment: How do you get that it's infinite? By the ratio test I have $$\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\ln ^{n+1}\left(3\right)\left(x-1\right)^{n+1}}{3\left(n+1\right)!}\cdot \frac{3n!}{\left(-1\right)^n\ln ^n\left(3\right)\left(x-1\right)^n}\right| = \frac{\ln \left(3\right)\left|x-1\right|}{\left|n+1\right|}$$ but what is the conclusion from here? @zwim

Comment: Well that goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ so the radius is infinite.